# La forme du pronom personnel dans un contexte particulier

Tags: pronoms-personnels, antécédent

On trouve assez souvent des phrases du modèle ci-dessous.

- Nous avons fourni des moyens mathématiques le plus simples possible afin de **se** doter de possibilités immédiates de raisonnement, cependant sans trop sacrifier à la rigueur.

On s'attend, si peut être pas à ce que les personnes *dotées* soient celles qui écrivent, c'est à dire celles rédigeant une préface ou développant une explication, à ce que ces personnes soient les lecteurs, les étudiants qui suivent l'explication et donc à un choix de pronom parmi les suivants ou bien à un nom en tant qu'objet de « doter »;

> **les, vous**, nous, (difficilement) **le** ou **la** (« **la** » pour la classe peut être), (certainement pas) **te**

Cependant selon le TLFi la définition de « se » est

> « Pron. pers. non prédicatif de la **3<sup>e</sup> pers.**, signe de la voix pronom., sans marque de nombre ou de genre ».

Il s'ensuit que l'antécédent n'est ni celui ou ceux qui écrivent ni ceux à qui ces derniers s'adressent.

Est-ce qu'il existe une « reconversion » récente de ce pronom qui fasse qu'il faille l'interpréter comme un pronom de la 1<sup>re</sup> personne du pluriel  ou s'agit-il plutôt d'un glissement collectif qui « amène » le pronom dans cette catégorie et qui pour l'instant n'est donc qu'une erreur ?

Comment: Une recherche de la phrase citée ne donne rien. Y a-t-il des exemples reposant sur des sources disponibles ? D'autre part, ce doit être **les** plus simples possible.

Comment: @jlliagre Non,  la phrase citée ne peut pas être trouvée avec Google ; comme je le stipule, c'est le modèle, dans lequel les mots et la partie de la forme sans incidence sur le problème sont les miens ; ces changements visent à ne  pas signaler les auteurs : je ne sais pas trop si donner cette référence serait de bon gout. J'ai cependant une de ces références, c'est la dernière relecture qui a motivé ma question, que d'ailleurs j'ai eu depuis longtemps de façon récurrente dans d'autre ouvrages ; ces derniers seraient impossible à dénicher dans mes livres (je ne garde pas d'archive de cela).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

À ma connaissance il n'existe pas de "reconversion" de ce pronom.

Par contre cet usage irrégulier est relevé par certains dictionnaires :
http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/se

> **Rem.** ,,Le langage populaire met souvent, dans les verbes pronominaux à l'infinitif et au participe présent (ou gérondif), le pronom *se* où l'accord normal demanderait l'un des pronoms *me, te, nous, vous*: *Nous étions toujours à se disputer. En se pressant un peu, vous arriverez à temps.* Cet usage irrégulier se manifeste parfois même dans la langue littéraire: *Je me plais... sans* **se** *plaire. Ça dépend comme* (H. Lavedan, *Leur Cœur*, p. 101)`` (Grev. 1969, § 600, note 1). [...]

À mon sens si c'est un usage irrégulier qui ne se justifie en aucune façon, il s'agit d'une erreur.

Comment: Il faut croire alors que le  langage populaire s'insinue dangereusement dans la langue soutenue ; tous les exemples que j'ai rencontrés faisait partie d'écrits considérés comme sérieux.

Answer (score 2):

L'explication tient vraisemblablement à une assimilation de ***nous*** à ***on***, la phrase étant alors :

> (Nous,) **On** a fourni des moyens mathématiques les plus simples possible afin de **se** doter de possibilités immédiates de raisonnement, cependant sans trop sacrifier à la rigueur.

Dans ce cas, ***se*** est pleinement justifié : **on se** dote de possibilités.

Une autre hypothèse peut être la phrase :

> Nous avons fourni des moyens mathématiques les plus simples possible afin **qu'on se dote** de possibilités immédiates de raisonnement, cependant sans trop sacrifier à la rigueur.

dans laquelle ***qu'on se dote*** évolue naturellement vers ***de se doter***.

L'éloignement entre le ***nous*** et le ***se*** rend moins sensible leur discordance mais une phrase comme :

> Avec mes collègues coréens, pour se comprendre, nous parlons anglais.

ne choque plus grand monde.

Une rapide recherche sur Google Books rapporte quelques exemples de ces amalgames nous/on :

> - *Si l'on vient pour se battre, nous nous battrons.* *Notes et études documentaires*, *Numéros 3086 à 3115*, p 62, 1964.
> - *Pour se laver, nous devions casser la pellicule de glace qui s'était formée pendant la nuit.*, Isabelle Soulard, *Les femmes de l'Ouest sous l'Occupation*, 2002.
> - *Pour se laver, nous devons attendre que quelqu'un parte au puits chercher de l'eau*, Moussa Boureima, *La pagne de Barbara, 2006.
> - *Une ultime visite pour se reposer nous conduira aux lacs Myvatn et Askja, à la table volcanique de Herdubreid et au mont Krafla.*

---

> Est-ce qu'il existe une « reconversion » récente de ce pronom qui fasse qu'il faille l'interpréter comme un pronom de la **1<sup>re</sup>** personne du pluriel ?

Oui, et cette assimilation n'est pas nouvelle au moins en français parlé.

> ou s'agit-il plutôt d'un glissement collectif qui « amène » le pronom dans cette catégorie et qui pour l'instant n'est donc qu'une erreur ?

Il s'agit bien d'une évolution, plus précisément d'une irrégularité causée par la disparition de *nous* sujet en français où *on* est utilisé pour *nous* dans plus de 99% des cas à l'oral. Il ne s'agit donc pas pour moi d'une erreur, *ton kilométrage peut varier* ;-)

Comment: Cependant la phrase d'origine est bien écrite avec "nous". Le passage au registre familier en milieu de phrase, avec l'emploi de "on" pour dire "nous" me semble plus qu'improbable. De même il est improbable que les personnes désignées par le "nous" deviennent indéterminées en milieu de phrase.

Comment: @Aweuzegaga L'emploi de *on* pour dire *nous* (sujet) est généralisé en français parlé (Plus personne ne dit *Nous arrivons*, c'est *(Nous,) on arrive*). Il n'y a donc rien d'improbable ou d'étonnant à ce qu'il commence à s'immiscer dans le français écrit. D'autre part, il est aussi possible que le texte initial ait débuté par un *On a fourni* impersonnel et qu'un correcteur trop zélé l'ait remplacé par *nous avons fourni*.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais dit qu'il était improbable que le on (familier) s'immisce dans le français écrit. Je dis juste que dans la question posée le texte commence par un "nous" et pas par un "on". Mais à supposer qu'un _"correcteur trop zélé"_ ait effectué un remplacement, son zèle serait donc retombé après une petite dizaine de mots? Remplacer le "on" par nous, oui, mais remplacer le "se" par nous, trop d'efforts.

Comment: @Aweuzegaga Je ne suis pas ce correcteur trop zélé mais l'éloignement des pronoms peut facilement expliquer sa baisse de vigilance. D'autre part, je n'ai jamais dit que ce *se* respectait les prescriptions de la grammaire. J'apporte seulement une explication à cette évolution qui n'est pas nouvelle.

Comment: Tu apportes une explication à l'aide d'une supposition hasardeuse qui transforme la phrase de la question originale... En somme tu réponds à une autre question que celle posée. La question originale était de savoir si l'emploi du _se_ était une erreur dans la phrase proposée. Oui c'en est une. Il n'y a nul besoin d'inventer un correcteur zélé, un éloignement insurmontable de pronoms pour ce fameux personnage au zèle finalement très relatif, ou encore une nouvelle phrase encore plus mal écrite que la première pour justifier que cette première soit mal écrite.

Comment: @Aweuzegaga Non, la question posée ne demande pas si c'est une erreur. Elle demande laquelle de ces deux propositions est vraie:  A: **c'est une évolution de *vous*** et B: **c'est une erreur**. Elle indique aussi qu'il ne s'agit pas d'un cas isolé. Ma réponse ne considère pas qu'il s'agit d'une *erreur*. Même le TLFi ne le fait pas et cite un usage littéraire. Erroné et irrégulier ne sont pas synonymes.

Comment: Il y avait une erreur dans ma question : 1ière et non 3e personne. Si cette évolution que vous constatez est assez solide, quelles sources attestent du changement auquel nous conformer ? Le TLFi se limite à lister un pronom de la 3e personne. N'est-ce pas une chose assez irrationnelle que de tolérer dans la langue une forme de plus qui va être ambigüe, à la fois un pronom de la 3e personne et de la 1ière ?

Comment: @jlliagre Une évolution du pronom **se** pas du pronom **vous**... L'usage irrégulier indiqué précise bien que **se** remplace aléatoirement **me, te, nous, vous**, pas simplement **nous**. Et pour finir sur **irrégulier**, ça signifie bien **qui n'est pas conforme aux règles**... De là à parler d'erreur il n'y a qu'un pas que le TLFi a la politesse de ne pas franchir explicitement ; l'usage n'est pas valide pour autant.

Comment: @LPH Quelles sources ? Ta question en est une. Tu constates observer cet usage. Quant à tolérer ou pas, ce n'est pas ma vision de la linguistique. Certaines règles d'aujourd'hui étaient sans doute des irrégularités hier et des erreurs d'autrefois.

Comment: @Aweuzegaga Les verbes irréguliers ne sont pas des verbes erronés.

Comment: Ma question est une source, oui, mais une "micro source" ; évidemment je ne parle que  de sources dont les assertions reposent sur une évaluation globale, suffisamment sure, qui repose sur une analyse importante : une source comme par exemple un grammairien qui nous dirait « nous pouvons considérer cela correct vu l'usage important constaté » ou encore une source comme un dictionnaire qui listerait le pronom en temps que pronom 1ière personne ». C'est pourtant vous qui déclariez très récemment que le descriptivisme avait ses limites ! La limite  n'a pas été atteinte pour ce pronom alors !

Comment: @jlliagre aucun rapport entre un verbe appelé verbe irrégulier et un emploi de pronom qualifié d'irrégulier (l'emploi, pas le pronom)...